# Display the name of all running processes in Linux in a file using a bash script

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to display the name of all running processes in Linux in a file using a bash script. I wrote the code, but didnt succeed:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in `ps aux| awk '{print $5}'`; 
echo $i > /tmp/test; 
done
```

Need your assistance, Thanks.

Comment: remove the for loop and the echo. Just pipe ps thru awk and save to a file

Comment: What do you mean with *name*? Do you mean *command*?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `for`, the syntax is slightly different:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
cat /dev/null > /tmp/test
for i in $(ps aux | awk '{print $5}'); do
    echo $i >> /tmp/test;
done
```

1. You missed the `do` operator
2. The output redirector `>` on a loop should change to appending `>>`, otherwise only the last value of the loop will be saved.

But as @stark said, the `for` is not required:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
ps aux | awk '{print $5}' > /tmp/test;
```

Comment: I'd rather not use /dev/null there. If you want to clean the file, you can remove it `rm /tmp/test`  or just `> /tmp/test` to keep the file with its permissions but clear the context.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, what your output should look like. With your template, and the fixes from Glauco Leme, I only got the *VSZ* of all the processes.

I assume you need the *cmd* of each process, then you just can use `ps -e --no-headers --format cmd`.

In case you need it in a file:

```
ps -e --no-headers --format cmd > /tmp/test
```

I hope this will do what you need.